# Add Image in a stackpanel based on textbox input

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to add Image stored in ..\Resources\ebi.png in a stackpanel. Most of the times, the same image will be displayed in Stackpanel, depending on Textbox input "EtReqCount". Below is the sample code tried but getting error saying

> "Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget"

Below is the code tried:

```
    private BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("WpfApplication1;component/Resources/ebi.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

    private void EtReqCount_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        StackPanel dynamicStackPanel = new StackPanel();
        dynamicStackPanel.Width = 300;
        dynamicStackPanel.Height = 200;
        dynamicStackPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue);
        dynamicStackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        if (EtReqCount.Text != "")
        {

            for (int k = 1; k <= Int32.Parse(EtReqCount.Text); k++)
            {

                Image img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image(); // This makes the difference.
                img.Source = bmp;
                dynamicStackPanel.Children.Add(img);
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML Code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is apparent. The same image is already a child of the StackPanel, you cannot add it again and again.

Moreover, you should use a private memeber to hold the repetitively used bmp to save resource:

outside the class method, and inside class.cs:

```
private BitmapImage bmp=new BitmapImage(new Uri("/....../ebi.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

You can create new instances of the image:

```
for(int i=0; i<...;i++)
{
    img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();  // This makes the difference.
    img.Source = bmp;
    dynamicStackPanel.Children.Add(img);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response...Now there is no error...but I cant see my image in window.

Comment: Please clarify or provide more details, as it is hard to tell the real reasons with your such descriptions.

Comment: Please do not add your xaml here, add it to your post, not in comment.

Comment: On Running the code I cant see any image in my window...whereas the expectation is to see ebi.png image on entering value in textbox.

Comment: No one might help, if you don't offer enough clues.

Comment: My apology for being naive...but what I am trying to achieve is...I have one text box (user will input a number) and I have one image (ebi.png). As soon as user inputs a number in the text box, Image (ebi.png) should be displayed below the text box (if user gives 5, then ebi.png should be displayed 5 times). Now the problem I am facing with the above code is I am unable to see any image on entering number in text-box. Hope that clears...!!!

Comment: Isolate this question into two steps, first make sure you can see 1 image, and then handling input from textbox.